# Will an add-on mini macro lens for my mobile phone help get a blurry-background effect?

Tags: macro, depth-of-field, cameraphones

I am new to photography. I am really interested in taking close up photos (macro photography) of objects with a blurry background. But my mobile phone (a Sony Xperia Ion ) does not have the facility to adjust the aperture size. It's fixed to f/2.8 or something. So, I learned that blurring the background is not possible with this mobile camera.

Will attaching one of the mini macro lens now available for mobile phones (like [this one](http://www.ebay.com/itm/0-67x-Wide-Angle-Macro-Camera-Lens-for-Sony-Xperia-ion-P-U-Sola-Acro-S-VJTE008-/380541105115?pt=PDA_Accessories&hash=item589a0473db)) help with taking background blurry (macro) photos?

Answer (score 5):

Macro isn't about blurry background, macro is about taking photos of very small things - the physics of light and lenses makes it so that macro also makes the "depth of field" (the amount of stuff in focus) very small - but it's a side effect, the point of a macro lens is to be able to take pictures of things that are about the size of an insect or a small coin.

Now, about that specific lens attachment - It's a toy - you may enjoy if you like to take pictures of very small things but don't expect it to be more than a toy.

The image quality is going to bad and it's probably going to be difficult to use but if you like to take pictures of very small things then go for it - it's only $9 so the worst thing that can happen is that you waste $9

Answer (score 2):

Furthermore you can read this article to understand the blurring effect (which is implied by the deep of field) in macro photography : http://www.dpreview.com/articles/3064907237/depth-of-field-in-macro-photography

But be sure that you will not take macro photo of insect with a phone camera upagraded with a macro lense toy (you must be really close to your subject to take the photo with this material). You will just can take object in photo.

As said, it's only 9$... just buy it and enjoy ;)